# Outlier treatment in Weka Explorer

Tags: weka

Once outliers are identified in Weka, instead of removing them how do i treat the values. For example a dataset has column credit_balance which has values starting from 1 to 1000, and after applying formula for interquartile range we get the outlier records with values more than 800. So now instead of removing these records i want to replace the values 800 with mean as 300.
how can we do that in Weka Explorer?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Crude method : Explore with below navigation.
Flow > Preprocess > Filter > Choose > Filters > Unsupervised > Attribute > AddExpression – this option will create new field e.g : ifelse(a2 > 1000,200, 1)
here a2 - is your attribute number.

Limitation : This will work for specific attributes only.